# subversion e-mail notification

Tags: svn, email, hook, notifications

I would like my subversion to send me an e-mail (and my co-workers) on every commit.  There are many solutions to this, but I didn't find any that will enable me to use wildcard/regexp match on svn URL and use it to notify different group of people.

Anyone done that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [mailer.py](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py) supports regular expressions in the `for_paths` setting.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `svnlook` to get more details from the post-commit hook script, for example if you use a shell script. Some examples can also be found on the tigris website, like [this one](http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html#mailer_py), which uses Python.